# How to reset fadeOut function?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show text for a few seconds when a user clicks a button. At the moment, when I click the button the text shows and fades out, but I'm not able to repeat the action.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/gLeMZR

This is my code:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#add').hide();
  $('#remove').show();  
  $('#message').html('Added!').delay(3000).fadeOut();
})

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#remove').hide();
  $('#add').show();
  $('#message').html('Removed!').delay(3000).fadeOut();
})
```

Is there a way to reset the function so that it will work more than once?

Comment: You need `fadeIn()` after `fadeOut()`

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ojsuwup9/#&togetherjs=5DnFk30IAL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) before performing [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
$('#message').html('Removed!').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

hey just saw your code in code pen You just need to fadeIn() again to use it for next time..
here is your answer...

```
    $('#add').click(function() {
      $('#add').hide();
      $('#remove').show();
      $('#message').html('Added!').fadeIn();
      $('#message').html('Added!').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    })

    $('#remove').click(function() {
      $('#remove').hide();
      $('#add').show();
      $('#message').html('Added!').fadeIn();
      $('#message').html('Removed!').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    })
```

Comment: <pre>$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#add').hide();
  $('#remove').show();
 
  $('#message').html('Added!').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
})

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#remove').hide();
  $('#add').show();
  
  $('#message').html('Removed!').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
})

Comment: <pre>$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#add').hide();
  $('#remove').show();
 
  $('#message').html('Added!').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
})

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#remove').hide();
  $('#add').show();
  
  $('#message').html('Removed!').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
})</pre>

Answer (score 0):

you can try with setTimeout, like this...

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('#message').html('Removed!').fadeOut();
}, 3000); //3s
```